# Save content of div with local storage, and display on another page

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I am trying to grab the contents of a `<div>` on a page on page load, and save it to localstorage.

When someone visits the homepage again, I would like the contents of this `div` to be displayed.

Whilst I can get functions to work with the use of form input fields and a submit, I cannot find a way to get this working using just  contents and page load.

Any help appreciated!

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing your markup and code it's hard to know what might be the problem, you should be able to do something like the following

On the first page:

```
$(function() {
  localStorage["myKey"] = JSON.stringify($("#divWithContents").html());
});
```

On the page you want the contents displayed:

```
$(function() {
   if (localStorage["myKey"] != null) {
      var contentsOfOldDiv = JSON.parse(localStorage["myKey"]);    
      $("divWhereIwantStuffDisplayed").html(contentsOfOldDiv);
     } 
});
```

Comment: This is a great starting pt. displaying markup with local storage. Thanks!