# How to save a Web Page to continue working offline?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, offline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save content of div with local storage, and display on another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168734/save-content-of-div-with-local-storage-and-display-on-another-page)

I have built a Web page that loads data in an iframe and allows users to draw charts from it. The demo page is [here](http://usermanagedsolutions.com/Demos/Pages/MiniBIEditMode.aspx).

After users load the data and draw the chart, I'd like to give them the ability to save the page to their computer and continue using it offline (typically switch between the different chart types). Is there a way to do this?

What I have considered and doesn't seem to work:

- browser save as .html => only saves the page source.
- Internet Explorer save as .mht => saves page source and external files (scripts, css) but doesn't retain the iframe content.
- save page innerHTML => saves the content including the iframe, but
  doesn't retain the external scripts.

**[Update]** Several people have mentioned another post: "Save content of div with local storage, and display on another page". This is not what I am looking for, I need to save **both the content and the interaction** (scripts).

Comment: Have a look at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Comment: @Esailija ok, very interesting. But I am afraid it won't work for the iframe data. From your source, caching is only done once and seems better adapted to stable files like js libraries and css.

Comment: @Esailija could you explain why you provided an answer with application cache and at the same time voted my question as duplicate of another question that does NOT address the issue?

Comment: Cos I saw people going "perfect dupe", I trusted them to be right without thinking about it :P I can vote to reopen np

Comment: @Esailija that would be nice, if on second thoughts you agree that the two questions are different. I actually think your suggestion to use application cache will work, but as I am on asp.net (SharePoint) it is taking some additional effort to test it.

Answer (score 0):

*Browser save* only saves the HTML as it was originally loaded, it does not save STATE. You need to grab the innerHTML of the body, stringify it and use HTML5 local storage.

See: [Save content of div with local storage, and display on another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168734/save-content-of-div-with-local-storage-and-display-on-another-page)

Comment: Looks like a perfect candidate for a dupe.

Comment: I beg to disagree, see my update.

Comment: Additionally, local storage might not work in my case as it is bound to the domain.

Comment: I think a local server may be the only way to do this.

Comment: too bad, I felt I was getting pretty close with my investigations plus @Esailija 's comment on application cache.

Comment: The question has been closed and this is plain stupid. Local storage does NOT address my issue, and the other question doesn't address the local use of scripts. These are two completely different issues. @Esailija has actually posted an excellent comment and application cache might work, but I am still working on it.